# Formatting numbers for printing in Java

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting

I want to format my number when I print it. I'm using

```
private static DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#00");
```

the thing is it prints

```
-01  
05
```

I would like it to print

```
-1  
05
```

or

```
-01  
 05
```

Is there a way of doing this without using if statements?

Comment: It prints -01 05 but you would like it to print -01 05?

Comment: I still don't see a difference. Does he want a leading whitespace for positive numbers?

Comment: @JBNizet correct - for the purposes of right-aligning

Answer (score 4):

Well, apparently you can provide *two* formats, one for positive numbers and one for negative numbers. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

So you should use

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#00;#0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking DecimalFormat to do more than it does.  It only formats the *number*, if you want that number to be further formatted as a *String*, you need to combine it with a "String" `Formatter` ([javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)).

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(System.out);
DecimalFormat numFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#00");
formatter.format("%3s\n", numFormatter.format(-3));
formatter.format("%3s\n", numFormatter.format(11));
formatter.format("%3s\n", numFormatter.format(2));
```

output

```
-03
 11
 02
```

note that the string formatter aligns all strings to be three characters wide.  If you put in a value that is larger than three characters, then it will overflow the [width] of 3 (which is probably what you want).